# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

I'm just learning the ropes of Spring 3's annotation fu and I've stumbled upon the newb's nightmare exception. Would appreciate any help.

here's the form jsp code:

```
  <form:form method="POST" action="login.htm" modelAttribute="login">
  ....
  <form:input path="email" size="20" />
  ....
```

the controller code (at this point I'm simply testing the waters, so not directing to any page, just returning an empty string):

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(    @ModelAttribute("login") Login login,
                        BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println(" email entered "+ login.getEmail()+ "\n");
    return "test";
}
```

"Login" is a form bean with the appropriate setter and getters.

i presume this bit of code in my dispatcher servlet should take care of the annotation scanning:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.testAnnFu.controller" />
```

and this is the shameful exception getting thrown when i try to load my landing jsp page.

```
SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspx_meth_form_input_0(landing_jsp.java from :208)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspx_meth_form_form_0(landing_jsp.java from :164)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspService(landing_jsp.java from :107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

WARNING: ApplicationDispatcher[/sssmgt] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspx_meth_form_input_0(landing_jsp.java from :208)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspx_meth_form_form_0(landing_jsp.java from :164)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspService(landing_jsp.java from :107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspx_meth_form_input_0(landing_jsp.java from :208)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspx_meth_form_form_0(landing_jsp.java from :164)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.landing_jsp._jspService(landing_jsp.java from :107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I knocked off the **form:input** part and had a bare jsp page, that seems to load. only when i introduce the inputs are things going wrong.

i know there is something terribly wrong with my understanding of how this whole annotation thing gets wired up and maps to the ModelAttribute. I've rummaged through all combinations and posts in StOv for similar exceptions, but I've clearly missed something. could someone be so kind as to point out my blunder here?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069958/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request)

Comment: @Vincent-Ramdhanie  thanks for the note, but  I did check that post specifically and the recommended solutions of that post doesn't seem to work. as seen in my attached code, I've added the modelAttribute and binding result declarations. do let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: To me code snippet looks perfectly fine with spring 3. Does not spring automatically add the method parameter( annotated with @ModelAttribute ) in model ?

Comment: This is the solution for Spring 3...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621343/how-to-pass-variable-value-from-jstl-to-controller/40348514#40348514

Comment: SOLVED: took me a day to find the solution. This work for me using Spring 3...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621343/how-to-pass-variable-value-from-jstl-to-controller/40348514#40348514

Comment: I got this exception when I had a form tag inside another form. was a copy paste error...

Answer (score 196, accepted):

In the controller, you need to add the login object as an attribute of the model:

```
model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
```

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String displayLogin(Model model) { 
    model.addAttribute("login", new Login()); 
    return "login"; 
}
```

Comment: hey Vinay, just a clarification, and I do this within my controller?

Comment: yes;  In controller where you are calling login view. LIke.. @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayLogin( Model model) {

  model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
  return "login";
}

Comment: ahh... the basics are strong with you sir.. so my issue is that I'm heading over to the landing page and it's looking for a pre-instantiated model (which i don't have available), and so your answer is spot on. now excuse me while i go and bury myself deep in the groud. (a convenient way of adding a model to the view is to return a proper ModelAndView object like so: **return new ModelAndView("landing", "login", new Login());**  )

Comment: Finally! I have been reading documentation and hundreds of different posts around this problem for, ehm... a LONG period of time today. I had the exact same issue. Thank you both Vinay and Kaushik for clarifying and brining up the landing page!

Comment: Have provided some additional syntax's and explanation in my answer. DO check it out.

Comment: @Vinay To me code snippet by Kaushik Goyal looks perfectly fine in spring 3

Comment: His model is Login NOT Model. I can't use Model. I need to use my own Model class.

Comment: It won't even hit the controller if you do this

Answer (score 18):

You would have got this Exception while doing a `GET` on `http://localhost:8080/projectname/login`

As Vinay has correctly stated you can definitely use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String displayLogin(Model model) { 
    model.addAttribute("login", new Login()); 
    return "login"; 
}
```

But I am going to provide some alternative syntax which I think you were trying with Spring 3.0.

You can also achieve the above functionality with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String displayLogin(Login loginModel) { 
    return "login"; 
}
```

and it `login.jsp` (assuming you are using `InternalResourceViewResolver`) you can have

```
<form:form method="POST" action="login.htm" modelAttribute="login">
```

**Notice** : modelAttribute is `login` and not `loginModel`. It is as per the class name you provide in argument. But if you want to use `loginModel` as modelAttribute is jsp you can do the following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String displayLogin(@ModelAttribute("loginModel")Login loginModel) { 
    return "login"; 
}
```

and jsp would have

```
<form:form method="POST" action="login.htm" modelAttribute="loginModel">
```

I know there are just different ways for doing the same thing. But the most important point to note here -

**Imp Note**: When you add your model class in your methods argument (like `public String displayLogin(Login loginModel)`) it is automatically created and added to your Model object (which is why you can directly access it in JSP without manually putting it in model). Then it will search your request if request has attributes that it can map with the new ModelObject create. If yes Spring will inject values from request parameters to your custom model object class (Login in this case).

You can test this by doing

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String displayLogin(Login loginModel, Model model) { 
    System.out.println(model.asMap().get("login").equals(loginModel));
    return "login"; 
}
```

**Note** : Above creating of new custom model object may not hold true if you have given `@SessionAttributes({"login"})`. In this case it will get from session and populate values.

Comment: How can i use multiple modelAttribute in the same jsp page ?

Comment: This doesnt work at all. update

Answer (score 5):

the first time when you are returning your form make sure you pass the **model** **attribute** the form requires which can be done by adding the below code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Login login)
    return "test";
}
```

By default the model attribute name is taken as Bean class's name with first lowercase letter

By doing this the form which expects a backing object naming "login" will be made available to it

after the form is submitted you can do the validation by passing your bean object and bindingresult as the method parameters as shown below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(    @ModelAttribute("login") Login login,
                        BindingResult result)
```

Comment: wont work wont hit controller

Comment: @PhilipRego why?

Comment: inputs werent mapped to object

Answer (score 3):

I had problem like this, but with several "actions". My solution looks like this:

```
    <form method="POST" th:object="${searchRequest}" action="searchRequest" >
          <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
          <input type="submit" value="find" th:value="find" />
    </form>
        ...
    <form method="POST" th:object="${commodity}" >
        <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="add" />
    </form>
```

And controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/goods")
public class GoodsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = GET)
    public String showGoodsForm(Model model){
           model.addAttribute(new Commodity());
           model.addAttribute("searchRequest", new SearchRequest());
           return "goodsForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = POST)
    public ModelAndView processAddCommodities(
            @Valid Commodity commodity,
            Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("goodsForm");
            model.addObject("searchRequest", new SearchRequest());
            return model;
        }
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("redirect:/goods/" + commodity.getName());
        model.addObject(new Commodity());
        model.addObject("searchRequest", new SearchRequest());
        return model;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="searchRequest", method=POST)
    public String processFindCommodity(SearchRequest commodity, Model model) {
    ...
        return "catalog";
    }
```

I'm sure - here is not "best practice", but it is works without "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute".

Comment: @Philip Rego omg. this solution work here. https://github.com/fedorchuck/web-store

Comment: This question is about the jstl form tag. Which you're not using.

Comment: @Philip Rego , so it works and it hitting controller. No, it's not about jstl form tag, it's not included to the question. please read carefully.

Comment: Ok mate, in this case you should go to question about JSTL or ask your own. On this page you will not found the answer for your question. Just check the title of the question. I don't know how and why you are sure that here, on this page, should the answer for your question, even if it's not included to the author's question. And my answer fo the question: how to fix "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute", this solution work and yes, it is not about JSTL, but just because it's another topic.

Comment: My answer for fix issue "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute". And it's already helped for some persons. I included information into my answer, that "I had problem like this, but with several "actions"". I said "like" not "such".

Answer (score 1):

If you have Model or transfer object passed to GET method but still have this error, check naming of your variables. Use entity/transfer object names in camelcase. I had BusinessTripDTO object and named it 'trip' for short. It caused this error to occure, even I had all other parts in place. Renaming varaibles to businessTripDTO in Java and Thymeleaf solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`model.addAttribute("login", new Login());`

to your method ..

it will work..

Comment: wont work wont hit controller

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in IntelliJ IDEA.
My code was 100% correct, but after starting the Tomcat, you receive an exception. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult

**I just removed and added again Tomcat configuration.** And it worked for me.

A picture Tomcat configuration

[image]