# spring Form binding using path not attribute not working

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a form ,when I am using spring form tags with the path attribute,I get the following error
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'selectedPerson' available as request attribute**

However when I use the regular HTML input with the name attribute I don't see any issues.

What am I doing wrong.

Here is the controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/savePersonChanges.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView savePersonChanges(HttpSession session,@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="selectedPerson")PersonBean editedPersonBean,BindingResult bindingResult){
 ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
 mav.setViewName(LANDING_PAGE;
 mav.addObject(TAB_SELECTOR,"EditPerson");
    if(session!=null){
        Rpt_date=(java.util.Date)session.getAttribute("editDate");
    }
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        mav.addObject("errorDescription",errorDescription );

    }
    else{
            /* Call service that updates database with table changes */
        try{
        PersonService.updatePerson(Rpt_date, editedPersonBean
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.logError("Exception while updating Person", e.toString());

    }

    }
 return mav;
```

}

The form is as follows:

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="selectedPerson" id="editPersonForm">
 <table id="selectPerson">
 <tbody>
    <tr>
 <td>
 <select id="personId"  name="personId" onchange="getPersonDetails(this)">
 <c:choose> 
   <c:when test="${empty selectedPerson}">
     <option value="0" selected ="selected">Select A Person</option>
     <c:forEach var="personIdItem" items="${editPersonProperties.personproperties}">
     <option value="${personIdItem.personId}"><spring:escapeBody>${personIdItem.personName}</spring:escapeBody></option>    
  </c:forEach>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      <c:forEach var="personIdItem"    items="${editPersonProperties.personproperties}">
           <c:if test="${personIdItem.personId eq selectedPerson.personId}">
            <option value="${personIdItem.personId}"  selected ="selected">${personIdItem.personName}</option>  
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${personIdItem.personId ne selectedPerson}">
            <option value="${personIdItem.personId}"><spring:escapeBody>${personIdItem.personName}</spring:escapeBody></option> 
           </c:if>
       </c:forEach>
   </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>

   </select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>

<!-- Person Details -->
<table id="editPersonTable">
  <tr>
     <td>First Name</td>
     <td> <form:input type ="text" path="fname" value="${selectedPerson.fname}"></form:input></td>
     <td>Last Name</td>
     <td> <form:input type ="text" path="lname" value="${selectedPerson.lname}"/></td>
   </tr>
 </table>

 <div class="editcancelstyle">
 <input id="savebtn"  type="button" onclick="savePerson()" value="Save" />
 <input id="cancelbtn"  type="button" onclick="cancelPersonEdits ()"value="Cancel" />
 </div>
</form:form>
```

I understand that the path attribute will bind the field to the form. However, I keep getting the bind error. If I replace using plain HTML, the controller sees the edited values for the fname and lname for the SelectedPerson bean.

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8785223/1403447).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Where should I be adding the model.addAttribute? Should it be to the controller call that displays the form?

Comment: sorry- I am confused I expected the save method to have the form edited values in it. Should I have added the attribute to the model to the previous request mapping that populates the form ? I tried adding to the model but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem, when you do :

`<form:... modelAttribute="selectedPerson" ...>`, the *`selectedPerson`* is the key of model object mapped from the holder of both Model & View class ( ex : `ModelAndView`), suppose you bind a model in your controller with  `new ModelAndView ("yourForm", "selectedPerson", new Person())`,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/form")
    public ModelAndView userInput() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("personForm", "selectedPerson", new Person()); 
            return mv;
    }
```

now the `Person` is mapped with *`selectedPerson`* so when this *form* returned as the response from controller, your form has already been bound to the `Person` model, so that you use `path` to refer to this Person's attributes (ex. `path="name"` , means it refers to *Person*'s `name` attribute)

In your form, on `modelAttribute="selectedPerson"`, the `selectedPerson` is *not binded* to any models, since "*selectedPerson*" is *never* assigned to any object because you didn't do any binding first before processing ( submitting ) the form.

this is why you got

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
> target object for bean name 'selectedPerson' available as request
> attribute.
```

Note that to get this binding works, add also the following on the top of your form

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

you can then populate the fields of the form (assuming you put action="result.html"):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/result")
public ModelAndView processUser(  @ModelAttribute("selectedPerson") Person person, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("errorPage","message","Something goes wrong");
    }

   /*System.out.println(person.getName());*/

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("personResult");
    modelAndView.addObject("person", person);
    return modelAndView;
}
```