# Root url error in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application whose url is `localhost:8081/Zelda` but when I do `localhost:8081/Zelda/`, I get whitelabel error

[image: Error]

I want both url to work.

**index.jsp**

`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Zelda</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%--    <form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" modelAttribute="login"> --%>
        <form:form method="post" action="/Zelda/login" modelAttribute="login">
            Name<form:input path="name" />
            <br>
            Password<form:password path="password" />
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form:form>
    </body>
    </html>`

My controller code

**IndexController.java**

`@Controller
public class IndexController {`

```
@Autowired
LoginService loginService;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/login"})
public String getIndex(@ModelAttribute("login") LoginModel loginModel) {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doLogin(@ModelAttribute LoginModel loginModel, Model model) {
    TblUser user = loginService.doLogin(loginModel);
    model.addAttribute("login", user);
    return "abc";
}
```

`}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781558/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request)

Comment: @AndyMc, My question is different. What difference would a "/" make?

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @user27149, Added my controller code...