# what does "BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name "xyz" available as request attribute" mean

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

What does this mean what the compiler is trying to convey does it mean that the binding object is not available when the controller class makes a request using the model attribute, i can't wrap my head around whats causing this illegal state exception could some one please explain what it means

Comment: You can create ids programmically using UUID generator.

Comment: just ignore `id` in jsp, but provide generation strategy in `Entity` class

Comment: OMG you changed the question, ask separate one

Comment: @ShantaramTupe im really sorry about that im currently working on the project as i post, your advice was really helpfull, but once i did as you adviced after fixing errors after exceptions after errors this binding exception arised again and im really frustrated im sure you have been there im also being pressured to finish this by this weekend timeframe

Comment: follow [https://stackoverflow.com/q/8781558/3425489](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8781558/3425489)

Comment: @ShantaramTupe thanks a  lot bro that solved the error im more or less done thank you for really helping me bro may god  bless you