# Spring mvc throwing exception- IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean , when using form tld in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form, spring-tld

When i use plain html in jsp page , then app works fine , as i add form tag in jsp , it gives the exception , i have pasted my code and exception here , please help me out .i am not able able to resolve this and stuck from 3 days now. Whats going wrong here

> my dispatcher-servlet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.shweta.*" />
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

     <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
                  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
                  <property name="prefix">
                      <value>/WEB-INF/jspPages/</value>
                   </property>
                  <property name="suffix">
                     <value>.jsp</value>
                  </property>
            </bean>

    </beans>
```

> my web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringMVCForm</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

> my Controller class:

```
 package com.shweta.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.shweta.model.Employee;
import com.shweta.model.Test;

@Controller
//@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/submitForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String formSubmission(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,BindingResult bindingResult)
        {
            System.out.println("entered in @RequestMapping");
            System.out.println("printing employee from modelattribute");
            System.out.println(employee.getEmail());
            System.out.println(employee.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(employee.getLastName());
            System.out.println(employee.getSalary());
            //modelMap.addAttribute("employee", employee);
            return "EmployeeWelcome";

        }

}
```

> my employee jsp page :

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${msg}</h1>
<%-- <form:form action="employee/submitForm" method="post" > --%>

<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employee/submitForm" method="post" modelAttribute="employee">
  <!-- <div>
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
  </div> -->
  <div>
    First name:
    <form:input path="firstName"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lastName">
  </div>
  <div>
    E-mail:
    <input type="email" name="email">
  </div>
  <div>
   Salary:
    <input type="text" name="salary">
  </div>
  <div class="button">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

> my employee model class

```
package com.shweta.model;

public class Employee {

    String email;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Address address;
    long salary;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}


HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jspPages/EmployeeForm.jsp at line 22

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jspPages/EmployeeForm.jsp at line 22

19:   </div> -->
20:   <div>
21:     First name:
22:     <form:input path="firstName"/>
23:   </div>
24:   <div>
25:     Last name:
```

> Exception snippet

```
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:613)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:505)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'employee' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:163)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:356)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jspPages.EmployeeForm_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(EmployeeForm_jsp.java:214)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jspPages.EmployeeForm_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(EmployeeForm_jsp.java:158)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jspPages.EmployeeForm_jsp._jspService(EmployeeForm_jsp.java:104)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:472)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put bean into model before rendering the jsp.
For example, you need to declare a method below at `EmployeeController` and access the jsp through the method.

```
  @RequestMapping("index")
  public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
    return "EmployeeForm";
  }
```

Similar question: [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781558/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request)

Comment: i have created a different controller class for handling this :

`@Controller
public class IndexPageController {
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/fillForm")
 public String fillForm()
 {
  System.out.println("redirect to form page");
  
  return "EmployeeForm";
  
 }
 
}`

why no exception comes when i use simple html instead of form tag

Comment: This is because simple html doesn't require any java object when it is rendered.In contrast, jsp custom tags(e.g. `form:input`) usually access java objects.For example, when you render `<form:input path="firstName"/>` within `form:form`, the tag requires an object of `Employee` as a model attribute and internally invokes `Employee#getFirstName` by using reflection. Therefore, you encounter exception when you render `form:input` not putting bean into model.

Comment: thanks a lot this worked for me :)
But this leads to one more doubt , in the EmployeeForm.jsp , form is empty its to be filled by user , so invoking Employee#getFirstName will anyway not give anything. So why it gets invoked then ?

Comment: This is because in another use case a form may not be empty.In your use case, the from is empty but in another use case it may be filled with some value(e.g. example name). Please think about how does Spring/jsp know whether its form is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have not put a bean with the name "employee" into the model. You should inject one before rendering the view. Add a method to your controller to do that.

Comment: i have created a different controller class for handling this :

@Controller
public class IndexPageController {
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/fillForm")
 public String fillForm()
 {
  System.out.println("redirect to form page");
  
  return "EmployeeForm";
  
 }
 
}

why no exception comes when i use simple html instead of form tag