# attribute [path] is mandatory for tag error but path is specified

Tags: java, spring, jsp, data-binding

I have two sections of my application that up until now were separate. The report controller handled the reports, and the other handled the displaying of other information.

Now on the display is a number, that when clicked, should take the user to the report and populate its search parameters and display the results that the number showed.

So below is the top of the report controller that Im trying to format the data for

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchReport", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String searchReport(@Valid @ModelAttribute("ReportModel") thisReport ReportModel, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(required=false) String action, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Ive tried both of these to solve my binding issue(s)

```
model.addAttribute("reportModel", new ReportModel());
model.addAttribute("reportModel", null);
```

Here is where I try to create the data model on the jsp page so that the report controller will accept it and display the desired results.

```
<form:form method="post" id="reportForm" action="searchReport" modelAttribute="ReportModel">
    <form:input type="hidden" path="regionCode" id="regionCode" value="0" />
    <form:input type="hidden" path="locationCode" id="locationCode" value="0" />
    <form:input type="hidden" path="reportCode" id="reportCode" value="-1" />
    <form:input type="hidden" path="yearFrom" id="yearFrom" value="2020-07-22" />
    <form:input type="hidden" path="yearTo" id="yearTo" value="2020-07-22" />
    <form:input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form:form>
```

Currently the error I am getting is

> According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute [path] is mandatory for tag [input]

Which does match other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8781558/6891471) that have been asked but their solutions are either not working for me or Im attempting to implement them wrong.

I also had this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198050/what-causes-java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-ta) at one point.

I have tried using [core_rt jar](https://coderanch.com/t/438088/frameworks/TLD-attribute-directive-tag-file) instead, but as the project does not have that jar already, Im hesitant to include it.

When I try non-spring form, the page with the submit button loads, but when the submit is clicked, it goes to the report page, but the object sent to the controller is empty so I get an error `Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was unable to get my approach to the problem working, but one of my coworkers came at it from a different angle and helped to get it solved.

```
<td class="col-md-2">
    <form:form method="post" id="Form" action="refreshTransferToReport">                               
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='action' value='searchBtn' id="searchBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<spring:message code="common.search" /></button>
</form:form>
                            </td>
```

```java
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes; //no errors are displayed until you run without this

@RequestMapping(value = "/refreshTransferToReport", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public RedirectView refreshEnquiryToReport(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @ModelAttribute("criteriaForm") CLU oForm, BindingResult result, Model model,@RequestParam(value="action", required=false) String action, RedirectAttributes redir)
    {
        myModle thismodel = new myModel();
        
        thismodel.setRegionCode(0);
        thismodel.setLocationCode(0);
        thismodel.setCode("-1");
        thismodel.setStatusCode(0);
        thismodel.setYearFrom("2020-07-24");
        thismodel.setYearTo("2020-07-24");
        
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/searchReport",true);
        redir.addFlashAttribute("myModel",thismodel);
        redir.addFlashAttribute("action","searchBtn");
        return redirectView;
    }
```