# Unable to bind model in spring form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to create a Login form for an application with an username and password. I have assigned the model to the form using modelAttribute attribute and bound it to the controller using @ModelAttribute but I'm getting a java.lang.IllegalStateException.

I'm only testing the jsp page. It works if I remove the spring tags and place plain html tags. I don't know what is wrong here.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginModel' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:123) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:460) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:357) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.jsp.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(index_jsp.java:249) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jsp.views.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

**My controller**

```
@Controller
public class EmailController {

    @GetMapping({ "/index" })
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginCheck(@ModelAttribute("loginModel") Login login, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println("Login page");
        return "index";
    }
```

**Login model**

```
package com.danny.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Login {
    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<form:form action="loginCheck" name="loginForm" method="POST" modelAttribute="loginModel">
        <tr>
            <td>Email Address</td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><form:input type="text" path = "password" id="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Kindly see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781558/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-available-as-request

Comment: This didn't work. I tried removing the form:input tags and then it hits the controller and loads the page. If I add the form:input tags it throws this error.